# how to enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app

Tags: azure, deployment, blazor

I set environment variable using "setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"" in command prompt.
But I got same error as I got first time in deploying blazor server app to azure.

The error I got is here below.
[image]

Can someone help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Joon

Comment: It happens when I log in. Without logging it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You will find **`launchSettings.json`** file in \Properties folder of you application.Open launchSettings.json file and change the  **`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`**  to production

Comment: blazor .net 5 there is appsetting.json. I tried there too, but it won't work.